# How to fetch and display an array of network images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, list, image, dart, amazon-s3

I am fetching an array of images from AWS in a List and I am displaying it using .map. I don't know if I am doing it right. I am having an error `'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.` But works perfectly fine if I manually display it like this, `Image.network('https://thisIsJustSampleLink.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/id/sampleOnly/bb.jpg')`

Here is my code. Fetching data from the database. The babyimage[] is an array of images link from AWS.

```
List <String> _babyList = List();

Future<void> getApplicantInfo() async {
AuthService().getRequestorApplicants().then((val) async {

  requestorApplicants.clear();
  _babyList.clear();

  for (var i = 0; i < val.data.length; i++) {
    var temp = val.data[i];
    setState(() {
      requestorApplicants.add(new RequestorApplicantsList(
        parentname: temp['parentname'],
        babyname: temp['babyname'],
      ));
      _babyList.add(temp['babyimage[]']);
    });
  }

});
}
```

Displaying the list using Image.network

```
Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   child: ListView(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
   children: <Widget>[
   Column(
       children: _babyList.map((e) => Image.network(e)).toList(),
    ),
   ],
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

in this code `_babyList.map((e) => Image.network(e)).toList()` some of urls (or maybe all) are null. Add filter to remove null elements.

```
_babyList.where((e) => e != null).map((e) => Image.network(e)).toList(growable:false)
```

if they can't be null check your code, maybe there is a bug somwhere

Comment: Why do I get this type of error?  `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'` I tried to make it List<String> but same error appears. (edited)

Comment: I don't know why, but you can convert List<dynamic> to List<String>. dynamicList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the help!